# how to untrack svnbridge file from a TFS folder locally?

Tags: svn, tfs, svnbridge, team-explorer-everywhere

I'm using eclipse to build an android app which is tracked in TFS. There's a svnbridge installed on the server but I don't want to use it anymore so I installed the Team Explorer Everywhere eclipse plugin. But now in my project I have a lot of ..svnbridge folders that are messing all the project (+1000 errors). Is it possible to untrack these folders? And if so how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So they're under source control, but they shouldn't? Simply deleting them then should be the least dangerous command. There's also a [tf destroy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx) command that will remove these item irrevocably.